# Approximating expression where one variable is much bigger than another one

Tags: approximation

I'm trying to approximate a generic function `F[a,b,c]`, such as `(a + b) (b + c) (a + c)` or `(a + 2b) (b + c) (a + c)`, with the assumption `a>>b`. Meaning `a` is comparatively larger than `b`, but not necessarily larger than `c`. Nor is `b` necessarily larger than `c`. In limit form, I believe what I wish to express is `Limit[F[a,b,c],{a/b->Infinity}]`

The expected result, for the given examples, is `a (b + c) (a + c)`

I have tried all the usual ways of performing this, such as:

`Normal[(a + b) (b + c) (a + c) /. {a -> a + O[b]}]`

`Normal[Series[(a + b) (b + c) (a + c), {a, \[Infinity], 0}]]`

`Normal[Series[(a + b) (b + c) (a + c) /. b -> c/\[Epsilon], {\[Epsilon], 0, 0}]] /. {\[Epsilon] -> c/b}`

None of which work, as I suspected. All of these methods don't really capture `a>>b`, but instead use some feature of the expression to simulate the behavior of `a>>b`. For instance:

1. The big O notation trick works for expressions with decoupled cross terms, such as:

`Normal[(a + b) (a + c) /. {a -> a + O[b]}]` -> `a (a + c)`

but doesn't really work because ultimately `Normal` resolves these two expressions differently:

`Normal[a b + b O[b]]` -> `a b`

`Normal[a b + c O[b]]` -> `0`

which is not an issue, because that is what big O notation is meant to capture. This just means big O is not the way to go when trying for `a>>b` approximations, expect for certain cases.

2. Expansion of the expression in `a` about Infinity is not useful as it assumes that `a` is absolutely larger. Meaning `a` is larger than both `b` and `c`. Therefore,

`Normal[Series[(a + b) (b + c) (a + c), {a, \[Infinity], 0}]]`

should not, and does not, work.

3. The epsilon trick feels like it should work and does if we apply it toward a reciprocal function, such as:

`Normal[Series[1/((a + b) (b + c)) /. a -> b/\[Epsilon], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]] /. {\[Epsilon] -> b/a}` -> `1/(a (b + c))`

but fails for the original function and it's inverse:

`Normal[Series[1/((a + b) (b + c) (a + c)) /. a -> b/\[Epsilon], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]] /. {\[Epsilon] -> b/a}` -> `0`

I'm uncertain as to why, but I believe it has to do with the fact that there are two `a`s now being substituted.

Is there a way of doing this in Mathematica? Ideally, I'd like the method to work with the expression and the expression's inverse.

Answer (score 2):

You know `a>>b`. Just substitute `b -> eps a` , make a series expansion for small `eps` and reset the normalized result with `eps -> b/a`. That's all.

```
Simplify[Normal[ Series[(a + b) (b + c) (a + c) /. b -> eps a , {eps, 0,1}]] /. eps -> b/a ]
(*(a + c) (b c + a (b + c))*)
```

Comment: That's not returning the result a(b+c)(a+c)

Comment: This result is not the first order expansion of the expression!!

Comment: ...supplement: Your  result `a(b+c)(a+c) ` is not the first order expansion of the expression because `(b+c)(a+c)` also contributes to the expansion!